# Issue with push and mongoose results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is the code:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, usr){

 following = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < usr.follow.length; i++) {

    usermodel.findOne({ _id: usr.follow[i] }, function (err, followed){

        if (err) throw err;

        following.push(followed);

    });

  }

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(following);

      res.render('home.ejs', {

         user: usr,
         following: following 

      }); 

});
```

I'm trying to push all the `usermodel.find` into the array following. Inside the loop `for`, if I use `console.log(following)`, the console would show me the array with all the mongoose `find`results, but the problem is that, outside the `for`loop, the array `following` is empty! It's weird, and I don't know exactly what to do. Any solutions for this...?

Thank's advance!

Comment: That looks like an asynchronous mechanism. That's generally why APIs involve callback functions like that - the callbacks are not called immediately, but sometime in the future. Your code after the loop runs before any of those callbacks are even started, therefore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling async functions, which get executed sometime in the future, but you are expecting `following` to contain items in the present.

Your application should be restructured like this:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, usr){
following = [];
// i assume that usr.follow is an array
usermodel.find({ _id: { $in: usr.follow } }, function (err, userList){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(userList);
    res.render('home.ejs', {
        user: usr,
        following: userList
    });
});
```

Comment: Works! But just one question, what is `{ $in: usr.follow }`?

Comment: It specifies that the query must search for every `_id` which matches an element `$in` the array `usr.follow`. There are some good examples in the documentation [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/)